# C# Post Json String to Entity Model

Tags: c#, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to post a Json string, deserialize it, and then save it to a SQL database using MVC entity framework. Here is my model:

```
[Serializable]
public partial class employee
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string netid { get; set; }
    public string enumber { get; set; }
    public string peoplesoft { get; set; }
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    public string last_name { get; set; }
    public string mi { get; set; }
    public string prefix { get; set; }
    public string suffix { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string tenure_year { get; set; }
    public byte tenure_indicator { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> hire_date { get; set; }
    public string updated_by { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime created_at { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime updated_at { get; set; }
    public string gender { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> birth_date { get; set; }
}
```

My controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(ChadAPI.Models.Lookup.employee employee)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            db.employees.Add(employee);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return new JsonResult() { Data = employee, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };

        }

        return Content("Model State Invalid");
    }
```

And My View:

```
@model ChadAPI.Models.Lookup.employee

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.intellisense.js"></script>

<h2>Create</h2>


<input type="submit" id="Save" value="Save" />

<script>
$(function () {
    $("#Save").click(function () {
        alert("clicked!");
        var employee = {
            id: 77,
            netid: 'caw63231',
            enumber: '00000',
            peoplesoft: '1012481',
            firstname: 'Christian',
            updatedby: 'caw63231',
            createdat: '10/14/2013 3:02:46 PM',
            updatedat: '10/14/2013 3:02:46 PM'
        }
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Employees/Create",
            data: employee,
            success: function (data) {
                console.log("success!")
            },
            dataType: "json",
            traditional: true
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

When I press the button in the view nothing happens, and using Fiddler I can see that no JSON is passed whatsoever. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried putting a `console.log()` or `alert()` inside the click function to see if the click is firing?

Comment: Yes I tried this: success: function(data){
                        alert(data.Result)
                         }

Comment: try data : JSON.stringify(employeeArray)

Comment: `success: function(data) { alert(data.Result) }` is not going to tell you if the click is firing. That tells you if the ajax call was successful.

Comment: Please check if your view is implicitly using a shared _layout. The JQuery reference in this question is incomplete. You may need to actually reference the jquery JavaScript lib (if your view isn't using a layout somewhere that does already). Also, are you getting any JS errors in the browser?

Comment: Check your JavaScrip Section must begin with $(document).ready(function () { ... } isnt the JS will not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MVC will automatically map the JSON request to your Actions parameters. The action you have written will be expecting a string object and you are trying to  post it a JSON object containing an array.

You should update your action to receive an Employee object and post a JSON representation of this to the action. Like so:

```
$(function () {
$("#Save").click(function () {
    var employee = {
            id: 77,
            netid : 'cfw22511',
            enumber : '000000',
            peoplesoft : '2322381'
             //..... Add the rest of your data to the JSON object
        };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Employees/Create",
        data: employee,
        success: function(data){
            alert(data.Result)
        },
        dataType: "json",
        traditional: true
    });
});
```

});

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(CreateChadAPI.Models.Lookup.employee employee)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.employees.Add(employee);
            db.SaveChanges();
            db.SaveChanges();
            return new JsonResult() {Data = employee, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet};
        }
        return Content("Model State Invalid");
    }
```

Comment: I arrived at the same answer, with removal of the `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` attribute for testing.

Comment: Thanks for your explicit instructions. Please see the changes I made as I still am not getting anything to happen.

Answer (score 0):

Json is an object parsed as string, when sending this object to the server, MVC automatically convert it to the object, you don't have to do this by your self, so:

public ActionResult Create(ChadAPI.Models.Lookup.employee jsonemployee)

on the other side, create the same object' in Js:

var emp=new Object()
{
id:777,
}

also, check if your javascript code is running